# Trying to multiple two numbers entered in text fields and alert the answer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

Very new to javascript and jquery. Attempting an exercise and came up with this code which I was hoping would take the two numbers a user enters into text fields and on clicking the multiply button, it would alert() the answer.

```
<body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var first = $('#first').value;
        var second = $('#second').value;
        $('#multiply').click(function(){
            alert(first*second);
        }); // end click
    }); // end ready
</script>

First Number: 
<input type="text" id="first"><br >

Second Number: 
<input type="text" id="second"><br >

<input type="button" id="multiply" value="Multiply">
<input type="button" id="divide" value="Divide">

</body>
```

Comment: I would say you need to read the field values inside your click handler. `$('#multiply').click(function(){ var first = $('#first').value; var second = $('#second').value;alert(first*second);});` because outside it is executed after pageload before user entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#multiply').click(function(){
        var first = parseFloat($('#first').val());
        var second = parseFloat($('#second').val());
        console.log(first*second);
    }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

- `val()` is used to get the `value` from a jQuery object (or the value of the first element of a jQuery collection),
- `parseFloat()` is used to convert the `<input/>` elements' string into a number.

Incidentally, I'm using `console.log()`, instead of `window.alert()`, in order to be less frustrating the user. But, obviously, change that to your own taste (but logging to the console doesn't require a user-action to dismiss).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- jQuery:

  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: also put the vals inside the click handler, or they will have the values from when the page was originally loaded (nothing)

Comment: @Austin: embarrassingly enough, I hadn't actually realised until your comment that they weren't inside the click-handler... >.<

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you that worked perfectly. Onwards and upwards.

Comment: What if we have multiple input fields instead of two input fields?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `value` property in a jQuery object, use the `val` method to get the value from the inputs:

```
var first = $('#first').val();
var second = $('#second').val();
```

Right now you have the code for getting the values when the page loads, but you should get the values when the click happens:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#multiply').click(function(){
        var first = $('#first').val();
        var second = $('#second').val();
        alert(first * second);
    }); // end click
}); // end ready
```

You are using implicit conversion from strings to numbers when you do the multiplication. You might want to explicitly parse the strings, it's good practice to make sure that the data is of the correct type rather than relying on implicit conversions. If you for example want to add numbers, the implicit conversion won't work there, as the `+` operator also is used to concatenate strings. Use the `parseInt` or `parseFloat` methods to parse strings into numbers. Example:

```
var first = parseInt($('#first').val(), 10);
var second = parseInt($('#second').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you grab the value of a text field, the result is text. Not a number. You can parse the value into a number with the (globally available) parseFloat function (Or the parseInt function if there is no fractional value to the numbers).

```js
var first = parseFloat($("#first").val());
var second = parseFloat($('#second').val());
```

Comment: You are completely correct. I could have sworn it was both parseInt, and parseFloat, but that makes sense, since floats are pretty hard to represent in base 2, 8, or 16.

Answer (score 0):

$('#first') is a jQuery object, so you should use the .val() method. On the other hand, you are setting the variables when the DOM is ready, so it's not updating it when the user clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var first, second;
    $('#multiply').click(function () {
        first  = $('#first').val();
        second = $('#second').val();
        alert(first * second);
    });
});
```

In other things, your script tags should be at the end of the body. Script parsing is synchronous so the browser takes more time to get the DOM ready.
Have fun! :)